# Ubuntu - Postegresql server do not start

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I don't have experience with linux and I hope someone can help with this problem.

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and with an application that uses PostegreSQL 9.5. Everything has been working normally in last few months.

However, last weekend a power failure shut down all computers and when I turned on the server I noticed that the PostegreSQL it is not starting.

When I run the command

```
psql taiga -U postgres
```

I get

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Start command don`t return any error

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
[ ok ] Starting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.
```

And the status one shows that the service is not running

```
sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Seg 2017-07-03 13:04:43 BRT; 7min ago
   Process: 826 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 826 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Jul 03 13:04:43 vmtaiga systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jul 03 13:04:43 vmtaiga systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

The only way to get the server running is with the command

```
sudo su - postgres
postgres@vmtaiga:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

After this I can connect to the database but the serve will stop if I close the terminal.

Please, anyone can help me fix this problem?

Comment: does the postgresql service start after reboot? is the postgresql service enabled (man systemctl)?

Comment: the service does not start after reboot. only with the last command on the question the services starts and keeps running.